# database error : The TCP/IP connection to the host has failed. java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect

Tags: java

I have created a application where I am calling data from RFC Abap table and storing in SQL database for further use.
I am using eclipse for development.Now I am facing one issue here.I have scheduled two RFC's at 7 am and inserting data in two tables from two different RFC's. I am getting an error :

```
database error : The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed.      
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect.
```

Note: I am using two different eclipse for two different RFc's as calling in same eclipse in leading into heap dump error and data inconsistency.

Kindly help.

Comment: Commonly, in Java, you have this error when you try to **Bind** the same address (and port) twice or more

Comment: realistically we need code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This errors means that the IP address and port on which the database is trying to to listen is already occupied (probably by the second Eclipse instance).

You either need to configure the databases to use different ports (if you need two separate ones), or have both instances of your application connect to the same db.